# Data from a callback not storing on an array in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mongoose

Following is my code -

```
exports.saveWeekAvailability = function(req, res){
    console.log("-- SAVE WEEK WISE DATA --");

    weekData = req.body;
    var resultArr = [];
    for(var i=0; i< weekData.length; i++){
        Availability(weekData[i]).save(function(err, result){
            console.log("------------------------------------------");
            console.log(result);
            resultArr.push(result);
        });
    }
    console.log("-- Result Arr --");
    console.log(resultArr);

};
```

But every time `resultArr` is an empty array. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: are you getting the console.logs inside loop ?

Comment: @mithunsatheesh yes I am getting results in `console.log(result);` but `resultArr` remains blank :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate. Check comments to your answer for duplicated post which contains a very good answer if you want to understand what is going on.

A quick solution for your problem:

```
for(var i=0; i< weekData.length; i++){
   (function(j) {
        Availability(weekData[i]).save(function(err, result){
            console.log("------------------------------------------");
            console.log(result);
            resultArr.push(result);
            if ( j == weekData.length - 1 ) {
                console.log("-- Result Arr --");
                console.log(resultArr);
            }
        });
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: Thx..but to be very honest I tried ang googled before..but dont know this is a case of `closure`..so how do users expect from a novice to search with the right term and then downvote the question :(

Comment: This is what I tried too but no luck so I asked here http://pastebin.com/Zu0D7bVg

Comment: @Trialcoder, I read your code in pastebin, you can't return a value from inside a callback.